# Cannot invoke isEmpty() on the primitive type int or double

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, javafx

I am programing a JavaFX application where I am connecting my JavaFX TableView to my Sqlite database, and here I am trying to do is that if the textfield is empty, then it asks the user to please fill all the data. However, because in my Sqlite database I have 2 sets of data set in integer and one as a double, I cannot invoke the isEmpty to for those three sets of data. However, I cannot cast them to a String, as I will need to do calculations later on. One other aspect which is the last bit of code, is when the user wants to fill in the data to add a new set of data, he can clear whatever he was writing in those text fields, however, I am not sure what is the code for integers and doubles instead of "expeditionDate.setText(null);". Thank you in advance.

```
    String query = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    Expedition user = null;
    private boolean update;
    int studentId;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    private void save(MouseEvent event) {

        connection = DbConnect.connect();
        String Date = expeditionDate.getText();
        double Time = Double.valueOf(expeditionTime.getText());
        int Altitude = Integer.parseInt(expeditionAltitude.getText());
        int Distance = Integer.parseInt(expeditionDistance.getText());
        String Notes = expeditionNotes.getText();

        if (Date.isEmpty() || Time.isEmpty() || Altitude.isEmpty() || Distance.isEmpty()|| Notes.isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Please Fill All DATA");
            alert.showAndWait();

        } else {
            getQuery();
            insert();
            clean();

        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void clean() {
        expeditionDate.setText(null);
        expeditionTime.setText(null);
        expeditionAltitude.setValue(null);
        expeditionDistance.setValue(null);
        expeditionNotes.setText(null);
        
    }
```

Comment: If it were empty, Integer.parseInt would throw an exception.  You would not make it to an is empty check.

Comment: Follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).  These are 23 years old, but remain valid today for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Test to make sure the required data is in place **before** you even attempt to work the data and make a save or change to the Database:

```
@FXML
private void save(MouseEvent event) {
    if (aFormFieldIsEmpty()) {
       new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "One or more fields on the form is empty!\n"
            + "Data must be provided in all fields (except Notes)!").showAndWait();
        return;       
    }

    connection = DbConnect.connect();
    String Date = expeditionDate.getText();
    double Time = Double.valueOf(expeditionTime.getText());
    int Altitude = Integer.parseInt(expeditionAltitude.getText());
    int Distance = Integer.parseInt(expeditionDistance.getText());
    String Notes = expeditionNotes.getText();
    
    getQuery();
    insert();
    clean();
}

@FXML
public boolean aFormFieldIsEmpty() {
    return expeditionDate.getText().isEmpty() || 
           expeditionTime.getText().isEmpty() || 
           expeditionAltitude.getText().isEmpty() || 
           expeditionDistance.getText().isEmpty();
}

@FXML
private void clean() {
    expeditionDate.clear();
    expeditionTime.clear();
    expeditionAltitude.clear();
    expeditionDistance.clear();
    expeditionNotes.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double.valueOf will throw exception if getText() is empty but to perform other checks & better null handling -

Change

**double** Time = Double.valueOf(expeditionTime.getText());

to

**Double** Time = Double.valueOf(expeditionTime.getText());

Same for int - change int Altitude to Integer Altitude

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should not try to parse a literal into a numeric value if you are not sure if it is set correctly. Your problem is that you can't check if the value is empty, because primitive types don't have a built-in `isEmpty` method.

```
private boolean isEmpty(String value) {
    return value == null || value.trim().length() == 0;
}
```

I would use the above method to check if `expeditionTime.getText()` is null or empty, and if so, use the default value ie. `0.0` or any default value you would like to have.